# how to identify dominating email patterns in a list

Tags: java, regex

Is this possible, e.g:

```
jon.smith@abc.com
henry.smith@abc.com 
brian.smith@abc.com
jons@abc.com
john@abc.comenter
```

are email IDs of one domain
above e.g. the pattern that dominates is first.last name.

Is there a way in excel or any other way to recognize the dominating pattern from a list of emails?
This is just for one company abc

If there are ten domains with five emails each, then I should be able to find five dominating formats from these emails.

Wondering if anyone can help me  start off with my search and find a way to automate it.

Comment: Jumping in with regex is a wrong approach. Define "dominating pattern" with quantifiable property first, then write a problem to extract and compare those properties between different emails.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you are using regular expressions to categorize strings. This uses regex to match expressions containing a literal dot (.) before the @ sign. I have modified some code from [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) to fit email patterns.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class RegexMatches {
    public static void main(String args[]){

          // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
          String[] emails = {"jon.smith@abc.com", "jonsmith@abc.com"};
          String pattern = "\\w+[.]\\w+(?=@)";

          // Create a Pattern object
          Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);


    for (int i=0; i<emails.length; i++) {
    // Now create matcher object.
    String line = emails[i];
    System.out.println(line);
          Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
          if (m.find()) {
             System.out.println("MATCH");
          } else {
             System.out.println("NO MATCH");
          }
    }
       }
    }
```